# Использование математических операторов как элемент списка в Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

Всем привет.
Изучаю пролог и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
необходимо написать предикат, преобразующий арифметическую запись в инфиксную нотацию. Т.е.:

```
?- infix2prefix(a*2+3,L), infix2prefix(E,L).
L = [+, [*, a, 2], 3],
E = a*2+3 ;
```

В литературе, по которой изучаю, встречал похожий пример для формул и по его подобию написал следующее:

```
    infix2prefix(A,L):- atomic(A), L is [A].
    infix2prefix(A+B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L is [+,La,Lb].
    infix2prefix(A*B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L is [*,La,Lb].
    infix2prefix(A/B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L is [/,La,Lb].
    infix2prefix(A-B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L is [-,La,Lb].
```

Т.е. я проверяю является элемент атомом и пакую в список, а для 4 арифметических операторов я использую 4 случая, где проверяю рекурсивно соседние элементы. И ответы пакую в список.

Но пролог ругается на строчки с арифметическими символами и выдаёт мне 4 ошибки

```
ERROR: Arithmetic: `[+,_766,_794]' is not a function 
ERROR: Arithmetic: `[*,_1728,_1756]' is not a function
ERROR: Arithmetic: `[/,_2690,_2718]' is not a function
ERROR: Arithmetic: `[-,_3652,_3680]' is not a function
```

В документации нашёл лишь использование арифметических функций.
Вопрос: как я могу использовать символы арифметических функций, чтобы пролог не рассматривал их лишь как арифметическую функцию, а рассматривал именно как часть термы?

Comment: какая версия пролога? Из какой литературы брал пример?

Comment: Prolog: Multi-Threaded 8.1.15.
Литература: Clocksin, Programming in Prolog. 5th edition,

Comment: то есть SWI-Proplog?

Comment: Да, именно он. В тегах вроде бы тоже указал.

Comment: `is` используется для вычисления арифметических функций, в твоем случае ты хочешь сопоставить переменной значение справа

Comment: Спасибо! И вправду именно в этом месте ошибся. Заменил на = и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дал Grundy - у меня была синтаксическая ошибка. если заменить is на "=", то всё работает.

```
infix2prefix(A,L):- atomic(A), L is [A].
infix2prefix(A+B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L = [+,La,Lb].
infix2prefix(A*B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L = [*,La,Lb].
infix2prefix(A/B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L = [/,La,Lb].
infix2prefix(A-B,L):- infix2prefix(A,La), infix2prefix(B,Lb), L = [-,La,Lb].
```